# Material React Pagination, Change Rows Per Page

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Does Material React Pagination component have Page Size option (Rows per page)? I don't see it in the API listed. I know TablePagination component does, however regular component does not seem to .

```
<Pagination
```

https://mui.com/material-ui/react-pagination/

TablePagination has this, but not regular Pagination.

```
<TablePagination
  component="div"
  count={100}
  page={page}
  rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
```

[image]

Comment: hi @Akis rows per page

Comment: Do you mean this? https://mui.com/material-ui/react-pagination/#table-pagination

Comment: hi @KonradLinkowski I know that, just looking for regular pagination component

Comment: Why would regular pagination have this?

Comment: For the future, if you are working with a rest API that supports items per page, then use a drop down to send the per-page value to the endpoint and then get that data into your regular pagination component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. `rowsPerPage` is not available in the Pagination component.

The [MUI docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-pagination/#table-pagination) say:

> The Pagination component was designed to paginate a list of arbitrary items...

This means that the **[Pagination](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/pagination/#props)** component does not make assumptions about the type of content that is being divided into pages. The content is *arbitrary*. The docs continue to say:

> It's preferred in contexts where SEO is important, for instance, a blog.

So, for example the content could be a flow of continuous text.

The **[TablePagination](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/table-pagination/#props)** component has a prop explicitly for `rowsPerPage` because it was designed:

> For the pagination of a large set of tabular data...

Here, the content is assumed to be items delimited by rows rather than an arbitrary flow of content.

Answer (score 1):

1. add this to your `<DataGrid/>`

```js
components={
      {
          "Pagination": () => (<Pagination rowsPerPageOptions={rowsPerPageOptions}/>)
      }
  }
```

2. this is the custom pagination component

```js
import React from "react";
import {Box, Pagination as PaginationBase, TablePagination} from "@mui/material";
import {DataGrid, gridPageCountSelector, gridPageSelector, gridRowCountSelector, GridToolbar, useGridApiContext, useGridSelector} from "@mui/x-data-grid";
import {gridPageSizeSelector} from "@mui/x-data-grid/hooks/features/pagination/gridPaginationSelector";

function Pagination({rowsPerPageOptions}) {
    const gridApiContext = useGridApiContext();

    const page = useGridSelector(gridApiContext, gridPageSelector);
    const rowCount = useGridSelector(gridApiContext, gridRowCountSelector);
    const pageCount = useGridSelector(gridApiContext, gridPageCountSelector);
    const pageSize = useGridSelector(gridApiContext, gridPageSizeSelector);

    const handleChangePage = (event, newPage) => {
        gridApiContext.current.setPage(newPage);
    };

    const handleChangePageSize = (event) => {
        gridApiContext.current.setPageSize(parseInt(event.target.value, 10));
        gridApiContext.current.setPage(0);
    };

    return (
        <TablePagination className="pagination-container"
                         component="div"
                         count={rowCount}
                         page={page}
                         rowsPerPage={pageSize}
                         onRowsPerPageChange={handleChangePageSize}
                         onPageChange={handleChangePage}
                         rowsPerPageOptions={rowsPerPageOptions}
                         ActionsComponent={() => (
                             <PaginationBase className="pagination-pages"
                                             color="primary"
                                             variant="outlined"
                                             shape="rounded"
                                             page={page + 1}
                                             count={pageCount}
                                             onChange={(event, page) => handleChangePage(event, page - 1)}
                             />
                         )}
        />
    );
}
```

3. this is the css

```css
.pagination-container
{
    flex: 1 0 auto;

    .pagination-pages
    {
        flex: 1 0 auto;
        padding-left: 1rem;
    }
}
```